# iTextSharp , Duplicate Field Name when Merging Files

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextSharp and creating multipliable page from a single PDF form template. Each new page has a combination of new form field name but some are not changed, I want these field name to remain the same. I have no problem with the field names that need to changed. The problem is when I merge the different pages the field name that I want stay the same (duplicate) are changed, well not all of the, I am using PdfSmartCopy and some of them are not changed.
I can’t seem to find a solution, is there one? Can someone help?

Comment: Please post your pivotal code an share sample files to reproduce the issue with.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved - the problem was a bad PDF template file. Evidently the template was made with a non-adobe product. Once it was recreated with an Adobe product all worked.

Thank you all that spent time reviewing this post.